# How to get the current channel of WiFi card from shell?

Tags: networking, drivers, bash

I want to promatically set channel of WiFI card with shell script. Currently, I have the following script:

- `/etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  # tell wlan0 will be controlled manually
  iface wlan0 inet manual
  ```
- `setup.sh`

  ```
  iw dev wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor
  # wait until mon0 is successfully created
  ip link show mon0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
  while [ $? -ne 0 ]
  do
          ip link show mon0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
  done

  ifconfig mon0 up
  # wait until mon0 is activated
  ifconfig mon0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
  while [ $? -ne 0 ]
  do
          ifconfig mon0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
  done

  iw mon0 set channel 1 HT20
  ```

And then, I can set channel of WiFI card by typing `[sudo] ./setup.sh`

However, I wonder if there is a way to wait until WiFi card actually sets its channel to 1 by the last command `iw mon0 set channel ...`.

i.e., in pseudocode

```
iw mon0 set channel 1 HT20
channel = get_wifi_current_channel
while [ "$channel"-ne 1 ]
do
    ;
done
```

and I am looking for a proper one of `get_wifi_current_channel`

One thing I have found is `iwconfig mon0`:

```
$ iwconfig mon0
mon0    IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Tx-Power=15 dBm
...
```

If there is nothing for `get_wifi_current_channel`, I can make a script or a program manipulating the output of `iwconfig mon0`.

Comment: Just a quick note: `iwconfig mon0 | sed -n -r 's/.*(2\.[0-9]{3}).*/\1/p'` gives me `2.412`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a program to see channels used by wifi networks (similar to Vistumbler) in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309458/is-there-a-program-to-see-channels-used-by-wifi-networks-similar-to-vistumbler) - at least few answers there deal with the command line.